# Limite de caracteres en una tabla en un sitio web

Tags: html, css

Cordial saludo.
En mi sitio web tengo una tabla que muestra datos extraídos por medio de una consulta en SQL SERVER.
La tabla la genero así:

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <caption>Resumen informe analisis aceites</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="TablaCampos">
                    <td>OBRA</td>
                    <td>OBSERVACIONES</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php if(!$stml1) { ?>
                <tr>
                     <td colspan="6">No hay datos para mostrar</td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
            else {
                while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stml1)) { ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="TablaRegistros">
                             <td><?php echo $row['obra'];?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $row['observaciones'];?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            <?php
                }//Fin while
                }//Fin if
            ?>
```

Estas son las clases que utilizo:

```
.TablaCampos{
    background-color: rgba(105,144,207,1); 
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.TablaRegistros{
    background-color: rgba(167,187,219,1); 
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

La consulta no muestra todos los datos que si se ven en SQL SERVER, pues en SQL SERVER se muestran 102 registros y en la pagina web solo se muestran 33.

Analizando la información, identifique que en el campo OBSERVACIONES, hay registros que van desde 4 caracteres hasta 7028.

Revisando los 33 datos que aparecen en la pagina web, note que el dato 34 (fila 34), en el campo OBSERVACIONES, no es mostrado porque tiene 2206 caracteres y que esto interrumpe para poder mostrar tanto este dato como los demás. Lo que quiere decir que en la pagina web solo se mostraran los datos cuyos registros contengan menos de 2206 caracteres y que una vez llegue a un registro superior a este numero de caracteres, se finaliza lo que se puede ver en la pagina web.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma para poder mostrar esos datos también.

Comment: No había escuchado de límite de caracteres en tablas, pero puedes probar insertando el resultado en un `textarea` dentro del `td` observación y cambia el valor de los atributos `rows` y `cols`... `<td><textarea rows="10" cols="50"><?php echo $row['observaciones'];?></textarea></td>`

Comment: Verificastes el campo `observaciones` en tu tabla? Que tipo de dato es y cuanto es su limite?

Comment: Cordial saludo. en la tabla de SQL SERVER, el dato es un VARCHAR(MAX). En SQL SERVER puedo ver todos los datos, el problema esta cuando los quiero mostrar en el sito web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como el dato que me estaba impidiendo mostrar la totalidad de registros de la tabla, no era un dato relevante a mostrar en la pagina web, tomamos la decisión de no incluirlo. De esta forma logramos el funcionamiento esperado en la pagina web.